# Chrome developer tools computed tab doesn't show any CSS source reference lines

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

*Chrome Developer Tools > Inspect Element > Computed* doesn't point to corresponding line in CSS source for any of the elements – while Firefox does, for the same page. I tried both in Chrome (beta) and Canary, and on another computer as well (both OS X).

I have also clicked 'Restored defaults & reload' button, to no avail.

[image: chrome firefox developer tools not showing css lines]

Answer (score 0):

I (sadly) found the answer. It seems this is the default behaviour has been changed:

> somewhere around version 43.0.2357.81 m the layout of Computed Styles has now changed.

See: [Return Chrome developer tools “computed” to expand/collapse style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793811/return-chrome-developer-tools-computed-to-expand-collapse-style).